# Como criar um array javascript no formato json

Tags: javascript

Exmeplo de como declarar em php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696211_200x150.jpg
    [1] => http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696227_200x150.jpg
    [2] => http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696217_200x150.jpg
    [3] => http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696211_200x150.jpg
)
```

Comment: Em JSON isso seria uma string com este formato:

    `[
        "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696211_200x150.jpg", 
        "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696227_200x150.jpg", 
        "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696217_200x150.jpg",
        "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696211_200x150.jpg"
    ]`

Comment: A pergunta era só isso? ou procuras algo mais com essa array?

Comment: Eu queria, construir um array json com índice  explicito, como a do exemplo

Comment: Você quer construir um *array* com índices explícitos, mas informa que uma resposta que constrói um objeto sem índices explícitos era o que queria? Isso não fez muito sentido, então votei para fechar a pergunta como insuficientemente clara.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo para declarar:

```
var myJson = {
'img' : [
 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696211_200x150.jpg',
 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696227_200x150.jpg',
 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696227_200x150.jpg',
 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/637696227_200x150.jpg'
]
}
```

Exemplo para acessar:

```
myJson.img[0]
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: Entendi, era isso ai cara, muito bom..

Comment: Acho que você pode escolher a melhor resposta e fechar pergunta. Talvez editar a pergunta, pois algumas pessoas não entenderam.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar a função json_encode nesse array

Exemplo:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```